# Android IPC security between system services

Tags: android, security, service, ipc

I added a system service in SystemServer in Framework layer.

```
interface IAService {

    void valueChange(int value)
}

public class XXXService extends IAService.Stub {

}
```

And I want that this service can be called like below by only another system service.

```
IAService service = IAService.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("A"));
serivce.valueChange("0");
```

But, if someone get this service instance using ServiceManager as reflection way.

They can try IPC.

Can we allow this only for another system service?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is-  people use all sorts of hidden services via reflection.  Your best bet is to secure it with a system level permission, so that anyone without that permission gets an exception thrown when they try to call your methods.

Comment: If someone knows that they can get illegal gains when they try this IPC, they will try. Anyway.. :) how do we know caller has system level permission in callee side?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingPermission%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: You call it on your service.  If you're processing a request via a Binder using IPC, it will return the permissions of the calling app.

Comment: As I mentioned, IPC called between 2 system services only.

Comment: What you want doesn't exist, short of a custom build of Android.  This is the closest you'll get.